# newton square root algorithm condition confusion?

Tags: algorithm

the algorithm is pretty straight forward I implemented it as soon as I saw newtons equation

```
function sq(x , e , g ){
  g = g || x / 2
  if(Math.abs( g * g - x ) < e )
    return g 
  else
    return sq( x , e , ( g + x / g ) / 2 )
}
```

now here is the thing on really small values the algorithm gives a way off answer and on really large values the algorithm exceeds the call stack .

I understand why

what I don't understand is in the first condition .. 
`if(Math.abs(g*g -x) < e )` why!! if we divide by x before comparing solves the problem e.g:
`if(Math.abs(g*g -x) / x < e)`

```
function sq(x , e , g ){
  g = g || x / 2
  if(Math.abs( g * g - x ) / x  < e )
    return g 
  else
    return sq( x , e , ( g + x / g ) / 2 )
}
```

call the function like this first arg is the number you wanna compute the square root of , second is epsilon which is the range is which when I get a value should be acceptable , you could define an initial guess as a third argument 
e.g:

`sq( 9 , 0.01)`

or:

`sq(9 , 0.01 , 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would specify ε as a fraction of `g`, not `x`, since normally you would want to say that the result has some precision ("six digits", for example) which is necessarily​ relative to the result. But it doesn't make much difference aside from interpreting the meaning of the ε parameter.

It is certainly the case that choosing some absolute error threshold makes no sense unless you know that the possible arguments are within a very restricted set of values.